# Создание валидных файлов .class из Java кода

Tags: java, файлы, компиляция, потоки-данных

Есть интерес в создании откомпилированного класс-файла прямо из кода.

Например, в методе `main()` используем следующий код:

```
File file = new File("C:/.../out/production/projectName/SomeClass.class");   
file.createNewFile();
```

Мы получили пустой файл `SomeClass.class`.

Теперь необходимо в него что-нибудь записать.
`OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file); 
os.write("public".getBytes());`

Такой подход не работает. На выходе имеем файл, который можно прочитать лишь *блокнотом*. Из среды разработки файл `SomeClass.class` *пустой*.

> Как записать в файлы .class байткод, который
>   будет понимать JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, надо знать [формат class-файлов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html). Во-вторых, надо знать [байткод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_Java) и правила его написания. Желательно знать принципы работы [вирутальной машины](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine). После освоения всего этого, можно взять инструмент манипуляции байткодом, вроде [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/), и написать собственный "компилятор"

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;

import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;

public class HelloClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassWriter cw=new ClassWriter(0);

        cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_PUBLIC+ACC_SUPER, "sample/HelloGen", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

        // Конструктор по умолчанию
        {
            MethodVisitor mv=cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }

        // Метод main
        {
            MethodVisitor mv=cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC+ACC_STATIC, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC,"java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitLdcInsn("Hello");
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        cw.visitEnd();

        // Сохраняем байткод на диск
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("/tmp/sample/HelloGen.class");
        out.write(cw.toByteArray());
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Или не погружаться слишком глубоко в велосипедостроение и использовать [Compiler API](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr199/index.html):

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Flags;
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type;
import com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager;
import com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacElements;
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name;


/**
 * Класс эмулирующий для компилятора файлы исходного кода
 * и позволяющий компилировать код прямо из памяти
 */
class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    private final String code;

    public JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        return code;
    }
}

public class CompilerDemo {
    private static final ClassLoader classLoader = ToolProvider.getSystemToolClassLoader();
    private static final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    /**
     * Метод формирующий абстрактное синтаксическое дерево
     * и преобразующий его в исходный код
     */
    private static String generateSource() {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        JavacFileManager.preRegister(ctx);
        TreeMaker treeMaker = TreeMaker.instance(ctx);
        JavacElements elements = JavacElements.instance(ctx);

        JCTree.JCModifiers modifiers = treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC);

        // Тело генерируемого метода
        JCTree.JCBlock methodBody = treeMaker.Block(0, List.of(
            treeMaker.Exec(
                treeMaker.Apply(
                    List.<JCTree.JCExpression>nil(),
                        treeMaker.Select(
                            treeMaker.Select(
                                treeMaker.Ident(
                                    elements.getName("System")
                                ),
                                elements.getName("out")
                            ),
                            elements.getName("println")
                        ),
                        List.<JCTree.JCExpression>of(
                            treeMaker.Literal("Hello, World!")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        // Определение генерируемого метода
        JCTree.JCMethodDecl method = treeMaker.MethodDef(
            modifiers,
            elements.getName("sayHi"),
            treeMaker.Type(new Type.JCVoidType()),
            List.<JCTree.JCTypeParameter>nil(),
            List.<JCTree.JCVariableDecl>nil(),
            List.<JCTree.JCExpression>nil(),
            methodBody,
            null
        );

        // Определение генерируемого класса
        JCTree.JCClassDecl tree = treeMaker.ClassDef(
            modifiers,
            elements.getName("Example"),
            List.<JCTree.JCTypeParameter>nil(),
            null,
            List.<JCTree.JCExpression>nil(),
            List.of(method)
        );

        return tree.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Метод компилирующий исходный код
     */
    public static void compile(Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits) {
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, compilationUnits);
        task.call();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.List<JavaFileObject> sources = new ArrayList<>();

        // Генерируем исходный код класса
        sources.add(new JavaSourceFromString("Example", generateSource()));

        // Компилируем сгенерированный код
        compile(sources);
    }
}
```

Comment: Неужели невозможно взять "заготовку" уже скопилированного класса, скажем в виде массива байт, и через FileOutputStream записать эти данные? Задача получить .class файл, который можно будет подгрузить в память. Класс по своему содержанию подойдет любой

Comment: Невозможно. Это равносильно попытке открыть блокнотом mp3-файл, записать в него текст песни, а потом удивиться, что она не проигрывается.

Comment: А если в методе main() сгенерировать файл .java можно ли его прямо из среды разработки на лету скомпилировать?

Comment: Второй пример из моего ответа показывает, как генерировать и компилировать классы на лету. А среда разработки в рантайме вообще никак участвовать не может.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо решение используя лишь стандартные библиотеки

Comment: Compiler API - стандартный модуль JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, надо делать `flush()` на `OutputStream`, чтобы данные сохранились.
Во-вторых, чтобы получить валидный `.class` файл, надо скомпилировать валидный Java код. А это не просто записать набор байтов в файл. Затем полученный `Class` можно сохранить в файл, или можно сразу загрузить и исполнить его. Да, это можно сделать из кода на Java. Совсем недавно на Хабре была [статья, как это делать в последних версиях Java](https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/429670/). Ну и погуглив тему компиляции java кода из java кода дальше, Вы обнаружите тысячи примеров.

Comment: Неужели не существует способа взять заготовку из скомпилированного class-файла и каким-то образом эти данные записать через поток в новоиспеченный файл .class? Задача получить абсолютно любой .class в рантайме, который можно будет подгрузить в память